# Replacing Bath Fan/Light Switch wiring

Tags: wiring, switch, exhaust-fan

I'm installing a new bath fan and the old fan had dual wall switches with wiring  like so: (One switch turned on/off the light and the other switch turned on/off the fan)

### [image: Old Switches]

The new fan has a single switch (with buttons) that looks like so:
[image: New Switch]

---

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to wire up the new switch. Help? Please?

The bath fan model is Home Netwerks Model # 7130-02-BT BUT the official instructions/installation video uses a different model with a rheostat and yellow wires. The instructions that came with imply that I should already have 2 blacks, a white and a green

Comment: It looks like you are short 1 wire or it was not wired correctly originally. Or the power goes to the light and fan then a switch leg was not marked. The first thing to do would be to identify if the hot wire is coming into the switch box or the light fan fixture a non contact voltage tester can help. Also a diagram of the wire colors connecting the fan and light.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the *inside* of the box?